# How to send password recovery in user's saved language?

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n, emails

I have set everything accordingly as described in different answers of all this kind of questions, But could not solve problem.

I want to sent password recovery email either in English or in German language depending on the user's saved language. I have added translation by enabling variable_translation sub module of internationalization module.

And email is being sending in English and German but Drupal choosing language that is current language of site instead of choosing user's saved language. I have also enabled the option "Follow the user's language preference." on this page `/admin/config/regional/language/configure`.

Can anybody help me what could be the problem?